# Continuous hmm parameter initialization

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, classification, speech, hidden-markov-models

I am using Kevin Murphy's HMM toolkit to build HMM's for Speech Emotion Recognition. I have extracted features from 120 speech signals to use in the HMM's. I am trying to build a HMM for each emotion and then pass in a unknown speech signal and classify this signal to a certain emotional class. The problem I am facing is initializing the parameters for multivariate HMM's. All the examples I have seen appear to use data sequences that are of the same length for parameter estimation for a mixture of Gaussian's. My question is how should I go about initializing each HMM where my Data sequences are of Different lengths. For example my input into the below function mixgauss_init "data":

```
[mu0, Sigma0] = mixgauss_init(Q*M, *data*, 'diag');
```

Is a cell array array that contains 120 different matrices, each matrix contains 13 rows * different length columns. When I use this in the above function I run into an error with "More Centers than Data".

Comment: You need to concatenate all features into a single array of the size 13 * total_frames.

Comment: Hi @NikolayShmyrev thanks that seems to work, many thanks!